# Andengine cannot update SetText within a Loop

Tags: java, andengine

```
private void shell_loops() {
    int x=house_no+1;
    for(int i =temp;i>0;i--){
        myhouse[x]++;
        x++;
            updatetext();
        if(x==2)
        {
            x=0;
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
private void updatetext() {
    text[0].setText(""+myhouse[0]);
    text[1].setText(""+myhouse[1]); 
}
```

the text must update every myhouse[] increment is change.
it run but the text update was only the last loop.

Comment: What is house_no? what is temp?

Comment: It is nothing important. what i need is to show the new value of my text in every loop. but the text in my GUI do not change every loop and instead, it only shows the output of the final loop. only on the final loop the text changes.

Comment: this event is within a ButtonSprite where it runs when i press the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably the Thread.sleep(1000); fault. Try using a timerHandler instead of it.

TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(1, true,  new ITimerCallback() {

```
@Override
public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

  updateText();
  if(i == maxNumberOfLoops) 
    // unregister your timer e.g unregisterTimerHandler(pTimerHandler);

}

});
```

//register your timer